# Logical error in DLLInsert()- Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, c++14, doubly-linked-list

I have problem in checking whether a position is available or not.
Structure of DLL node is :

```
struct DLLNode{
int data;
struct DLLNode * head;
struct DLLNode * prev;
};
```

A pointer to head of DLL is declared as`struct DLLNode * head ={0 , NULL , NULL};`
Insertion function is as :

```
void DLLInsert(struct DLLNode **head, int data, int position) {
int k = 1;
struct DLLNode *temp, *newNode;
newNode = (struct DLLNode *) malloc(sizeof ( struct DLLNode ));
if(!newNode) { //Always check for memory errors
 printf (“Memory Error”);
 return;
}
newNode→data = data;
if(position == 1) { //Inserting a node at the beginning
 newNode→next = *head;
 newNode→prev = NULL;
 if(*head) 
 (*head)→prev = newNode;
 *head = newNode;
 return;
}
temp = *head;
while ( (k < position – 1) && temp→next!=NULL) {
 temp = temp→next;
 k++;
}
if(k!=position){
 printf("Desired position does not exist\n");
}
newNode→next=temp→next;
newNode→prev=temp;
if(temp→next)
 temp→next→prev=newNode;
 temp→next=newNode;
return;
 }
```

Please check the logic for checking available position.
Note : **List is unsorted**.

Comment: Also tell me why head is declared as
struct DLLNode * head
not as 
DLLNode *head

Comment: ***Also tell me why head is declared as struct DLLNode*** That is `c` code instead of `c++`. Since you are asking this question, I assume you did not write this code.

Comment: @drescherjm You are right it's in my book and I am having trouble

Comment: `k!=position` check will always be true, because the loop just prior exits with `k == position - 1`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik please provide me correct code. Thanks!

Comment: Right. Should I also mop your floors, and take out your trash?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's to you.